# Output Entry Type and/ or Category

Tags: entry, entry-type

Total noob here.  Have managed to output entries and paginate them with this:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('woods').limit(5) as entries %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        ....
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

But I cannot figure out how to output just entries of a certain type or entries from a certain category within a category group.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('woods').type('mahogony').limit(5) %}
    {% for entry in entries %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

ain't flying me anywhere but into a tree.

I'm sure it is something basic.

Comment: That looks O.K. to me. What happens if you do this? `{{ craft.entries.section('woods').type('mahogony').limit(5).find()|length }}`

Answer (score 1):

When you added the `type` param to your `{% paginate %}` tag, you removed the `as entries` bit, which is required. (That tells the tag what variable name it should give to the current page’s entries.)

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('woods').type('mahogony').limit(5) as entries %}
```